# To access button from another class which is in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

My goal is to access the button and make the visibility to false from another class in vb.net

```
Dim obj = New MyClass()
obj.btnName.Visible = False
```

But it is throwing error as `"Object reference not set to an Instance"`

Comment: When does it thow the exception, on runtime? What is `MyClass`, an ASP.NET UserControl? Then this won't work since you cannot create a UserControl via constructor and expect that the controls are initialized. Instead you must use `page.LoadControl("MyClass.ascx")`

Comment: Where is the definition of `MyClass`?

Comment: please specify what you are doing with your MyClass class, and if you are initializing the button 'btnName'.

Comment: I am accessing a control which is in the aspx page from ascx page

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug to see if your button has been initialized the time you access it, and i think it is not. This is probably your are using this button before the form or the page has been loaded. Since instantiating the button will happen in the initialization portion of your code.

Try to initialize you class in

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dim obj = new Myclass();
}
```

and inside the New function in 'MyClass' class make sure your are initializing all the stuff you want to use.

Comment: That is the problem I also guessing. I don't know how to iniatalize. Can you explain that.

Comment: I can't understand this line `inside the New function in 'MyClass' class`. What it means.

Comment: i mean the your 'Sub New() End Sub'

Comment: Please, how to access the button in `aspx` page from `ascx` page. Thanks

Comment: While debugging, I placed the cursor on `btnName` and it is showing as `Nothing`

Comment: it means it hadnot been initialized

Answer (score 0):

hmm how about?

Dim obj as New MyClass()

obj.btnName.Visible = False